# in my code variable enter cannot be found by compiler...what to do?

Tags: java, do-while

/* Write a program that displays a menu with options 1. Add 2. Sub
Based on the options chosen, read 2 numbers and perform the relevant operation. After performing the operation, the program should ask the user if he wants to continue. If the user presses y or Y, then the program should continue displaying the menu else the program should terminate.
*/

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class menu
{

  public static void main(String args[]) 
   {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do 
          {

              System.out.println("enter 1 for add and 2 for sub");
              int a = sc.nextInt();
              System.out.println("enter two numbers");
              int b = sc.nextInt();
              int c = sc.nextInt();
              int d;
              if (a == 1)
               {
                 d = b + c;

                 System.out.println("sum  is" + d);

               } 
                else if (a == 2) 
              {

                d = b - c;
                System.out.println("difference is" + d);
              }
              System.out.println("to continue enter y or Y AND TO TERMINATE 
                     ANY OTHER SYMBOL");
              char enter = sc.next().charAt(0);

               } 
            while (enter == 'y');
            }
            }
```

Comment: First, please fix your indentation.  Indenting your lines a seemingly random number of spaces makes it difficult to tell where blocks begin and end.  It is likely that you are referring to `enter` in a place that the declaration of `enter` is out of scope.

Comment: Declare `char enter;` before your `do {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `enter` is not recognized by the `while` loop is because it is in the local scope of the `do` code block. I would suggest defining `enter` before the `do` block like so

```
char enter;
do { pass; } while(true);
```

This will make it accessible to the `while` loop's Boolean expression and allows you to initialize `enter` by simply doing this

```
enter = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

Comment: it works fine when i initialize at starting before do but the problem then arises is that how will the program terminate as the variable enter will be called only once ..i want it to be checked every time

Comment: Every time you iterate through the loop, the expression in the while portion of the loop is evaluted. If it is true, then the loop iterates. If it is false, it escapes the loop. Include `enter = sc.next().charAt(0);` in the do portion.

Comment: thanks a lot .... i am new to programming ..it was a simple thing yet i got in trouble for almost an hour ....thanks for helpinh